# Type of Bank Account for UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, money, proof-provenance-of-funds

Do I have to submit Bank Statements for both Current and Savings account or is Current account enough?

Answer (score 2):

There’s no right or wrong answer to this. You need to submit sufficient information to demonstrate the strength of your financial background and that you can credibly afford the trip. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)